Why the Fourier transform of dipole expectation value is proportional to the power?
I see many times in the Harmonic generation spectra: The coherently scattered light power at a given frequency co is proportional to the square of $D(\omega)$, the Fourier transform of the dipole expectation value $D(t)$. Thus we can take the square of its fourier transform to represent the coherent photon spectra? But I didn't find the analytical formula to see this result straightforwardly. Can someone explain it to me?

Hi Gene Vettel. Are you following a reference? Which author? Which page?

@Qmechanic I've seen this conclusion used in many articles. For example, in 'Nonlinear Light Scattering Accompanying Multiphoton Ionization' and 'Harmonic generation: Quantum-electrodynamical theory of the harmonic photon-number spectrum', etc. (both in first page) This's like a universal conclusion used in the context of Harmonic generation but I never find such straightforward expression. Thanks!

Well, it's not my area so I have no idea how to show a rigorous formal proof of this relation. But I can give you what I think is more than a hand-waving argument. Something like a formal-hand rigorous-waving proof.

We know that the average energy flow per unit time per unit area is (check it here, for example)
$$
I(t) = \epsilon_0c^2 |\vec E\times \vec B| = \epsilon_0c|\vec E(t)|^2
$$
Where I used $|\vec B| = c^{-1}|\vec E|$. Now, the electric field in question is the radiated one produced by the atom, due to its oscillating dipole moment $D(t)$. In Feynman lectures, it is given by
$$
\begin{align}
\vec E(\vec r,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}\biggl[
&\frac{3(\vec D^*\cdot\vec r)\vec r}{r^2}-
\vec D^*+\notag\\
&\frac{1}{c^2}
\{\ddot{\vec D}(t-r/c)\times\vec r\}\times\vec r
\biggr]
\end{align}
$$
Where $\vec D^*=\vec D(t-r/c)+\frac{r}{c}\,\dot{\vec D}(t-r/c)$.
Now, considering the time average
$$
\langle I\rangle= \frac 1T \int_0^T \epsilon_0c|E(t)|^2dt
$$
I think we can connect it to the frequency domain electric field through Plancherel identity (for this part I'm not sure, but there is this question where people discuss the Pointing vector in frequency domain)
$$
\langle I \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \epsilon_0c|E(\omega)|^2d\omega
$$
If we take the Fourier transform of the dipole electric field above, the time derivatives of $\vec D$ will simplify to algebraic expressions in $\omega$, and we will have something like
$$
\vec E(\vec r,\omega) = A(\vec r,\omega)\vec D(\omega)
$$
Where $A(\vec r,\omega)$ is a tensor. With this relation in the expression of the time averaged Poynting vector give us what you asked.

Thanks a lot! I got the similar explanation from someone one year ago but unfortuately it didn't stay long in my mind. But the final result is still not about the expectation value of dipole moment operator.

Well, but this is the quantum mechanical part. All that I did is considering just classical EM. But now if you take in accounting the quantum nature of the dipole moment, it doesn't have well defined values all the time. The best we can do is to consider the expectation value, like we do for position and momentum in Ehrenfest Theorem
